# How To Force User Agents To Use Later Available Version of HTTP?

Tags: http, udp, http2, litespeed, http3

A *OpenLiteSpeed Web Server* is running on *AlmaLinux 8*.

**HTTP/1.1**, **HTTP/2** and **HTTP/3 QUIC** are enabled.

**80/tcp**, **443/tcp** and **443/udp** ports are open publicly and permanently.

The server is sending the below `alt-svc` header:

```
h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"
```

The setup has been tested positive by [http3check](https://http3check.net/) succcessfully.

But the user agents, I mean, browsers are connecting through HTTP/1.1 most of the times. HTTP/2 are used by them sometimes. Usage of HTTP/3 is mere.

**What should be done to tell the browsers to prefer later versions of HTTP?**

Comment: This page gives you an overview, which [browser implements http/3](https://caniuse.com/http3). But this does not mean, that the browsers always prefer http/3 or able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> What should be done to tell the browsers to prefer later versions of HTTP?

In order to use HTTP/3

- The browser needs to have implemented it
- It must be able to communicate with UDP port 443 to your server. This means that HTTP/3 will not be used, if a HTTP or SOCKS proxy is involved (no UDP) or if UDP port 443 is blocked. Blocking is often done to enforce use of HTTP/2 or HTTP/1 in order to easy deep packet inspection

In order to use HTTP/2

- The browser needs to have implemented it
- It must be able to have connection to the server without SSL interception. With SSL interception typically the ALPN TLS extension is not forwarded to the server, but this extension is used to declare support for HTTP/2 to the server. Without this extension the server will not try. SSL interception is often done in corporate firewalls but also in many antivirus products. The downgrade to HTTP/1 in such cases is a welcome side effect since it makes traffic analysis easier.

Note that none of this here is in control of the server. These are all client-side issues which prevent your server to be accessed with HTTP/3. There is nothing you can do at the server side to fix the client side.

Comment: But many testing tools are reporting that they are being able to connect to the server through HTTP/3.

Comment: @AbdullahAs-Sadeed: The issues I've shown are all client-side issues which result in the client being unable to use HTTP/3 no matter if your server supports it. These issues cannot be fixed by the server.